# ORACLE Query Sum Group By Show Last ID

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle Query to SUM quantity on my table.

```
SELECT SEI_NO, SUM(T.QUANTITY) AS TOTAL
FROM WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT T
WHERE T.SUPPLIERID_FK = '62551'
GROUP BY T.SEI_NO
```

But now I want to add column Transaction ID at least last ID.

```
TR_ID | SEI_NO   | TOTAL
1     | SDGDFGSD | 2
2     | SDGDFGSD | 2
3     | SDGDFGSD1| 10
```

What I want to show:

```
TR_ID | SEI_NO   | TOTAL
1     | SDGDFGSD | 4
3     | SDGDFGSD1| 10
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What is unclear Mr. min. my post?

Comment: How are you getting duplicate values for `SEI_NO` in your output when `SEI_NO` is the only column you are grouping by in your query?

Comment: Your question says "last" ID but your required result shows earliest (first) ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT min(TR_ID) as  TR_ID,
    SEI_NO,
    SUM(T.QUANTITY) AS TOTAL
FROM   WA_II_TBL_TR_EQUIPMENT T
WHERE T.SUPPLIERID_FK = '62551'
GROUP BY T.SEI_NO
```

This should do the Trick.

Comment: @iamsankalp89 Can you clarify what that comment means?